# How can I install python3-clang on Linux Mint 18.04?

Tags: vim, python, aptitude, clang

I have a vim plugin called CLighter8 that requires the package python3-clang, but unfortnuately I can't find it in the default repository nor any other repository. So I can't really find a way to install it.
Is there a way to install it manually directly from the source? Without haveing to reinstall all the other python packages I installed through pip3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Mint 18.04 doesn't exist. Did you mean a version of Linux Mint which is based on Ubuntu 18.04?

I think what you want to install is [this](https://pypi.org/project/clang/). If so, you have to install clang first. You should get clang from the official clang repos found [here](http://apt.llvm.org/). You can run these commands to install clang 6.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 (or Linux Mint 19):

`$ wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -`
`$ sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-6.0 main" #replace this with "deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-7 main" for clang 7.0`
`$ sudo apt-get update`
`$ sudo apt-get install clang-6.0`

For more info see the above link to the LLVM project page.

Once you have installed clang, you can install the clang python package - `pip3 install clang`.

Also it looks like you should install `libclang-dev` after more carefully reading the project README.

Hope this helped!